# How to add shadow to a bitmap when drawing on canvas without turning off hardware acceleration?

Tags: android, canvas, view, shadow, hardware-acceleration

In my custom view drawing operation, I need to drop shadow while drawing multiple bitmaps.

With hardware acceleration turned on, I can't use setShadowLayer and if I turn it off then drawing become very slow. 
I was wondering if there is any alternative way to achieve same effect without turning hardware acceleration off.

PS: Creating my own shadow with BlurMaskFilter is also out of options because of same hardware acceleration limitation.

Comment: use some `Shader` then (`LinearGradient` or something) or use hand made 9patch drawable with a drop shadow